Fantasy series (that takes place in Scotland, I think) about a man who goes looking for his missing brother and ends up in a fantasy world
I'm looking for a series of books I read in 1990, or maybe 1989 (I remember reading them in Germany when I was in the Army).  To me, they looked new, but maybe had been published earlier.
The idea behind the series was that a man goes looking for his brother who disappeared while hiking.  The man is out in the wilderness and passes between some rocks (in a mountain?). He finds himself in a fantasy world.  I don't remember much about the world, other than that, in each book, the same evil entity tries to use the man to escape out into our world.  And, in each of the books, the man learns some vital trick for preventing the escape.  As I recall, in the first book, he learns to meditate by concentrating on a flame in a candle.
Does this sound familiar to anyone?  It'd be interesting to read the series again.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Does the protagonist visit the same world in each book?  It sounds like it, so if the evil keeps trying to get to our world every time he visits, why does he keep going back?

He goes back to different parts?  Or things are different.  I  recall going back was to find his brother.

The 'man looking for his brother in a fantasy world' bit makes me think of Philip Jose Farmer's "The Dungeon" series. But it's been so long and I can't remember if the other details match.

That's one I'm adding to the pending reads list but this was not it.
